# Numpy: how to retrieve k max values from each row?

Tags: numpy

I want to retrieve k max values from each row in a numpy array. I have been digging through the documentation but couldn't find an answer (I am probably looking in the wrong places).  Does anybody have a simple code snippet that does this?

thanks so much,

Diederik

Comment: Perhaps I'm overlooking something but wouldn't a simple sort and following slice suffice?

Comment: yep, didn't think about that (I knew I was overlooking something :)) if you post it as an answer then I'll give you the credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution:

```
some_array = numpy.random.randint(0, 10, 10)
top_items = numpy.sort(some_array)[-k:]
```

Or as a lambda:

```
max_values = lambda k, array: numpy.sort(array)[-k:]
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `np.sort(some_array)[:,-k:]` ?